# How do I get my taskbar to normal size in Windows?

Tags: windows, taskbar

I wanted to change the font of my laptop so I searched for it and did it by creating a Notepad file and then everything messed up. After that my icons got spaced out which I corrected through <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>  regedit and changing the spacing, but my taskbar got shrinked:

[image]

What I did:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Segoe UI (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Light (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Semibold (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Symbol (TrueType)"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]
"Segoe UI"="Gabriola"
```

How do I get back to normal taskbar?

Comment: What did you put in the Notepad file?

Comment: Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Segoe UI (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Light (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Semibold (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Symbol (TrueType)"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]

"Segoe UI"="Gabriola"    

this is the notepad file . video said that i need to change mynewfont to new font name whatever i wanted i.e, gabriola

Comment: Right click on the task bar. Uncheck (unselect) "Lock the task bar".   Now grab the top edge of the bar with your mouse and pull it up to make it larger.

Comment: already did that not working. it only pulls taskbar doesn't changes icon size or font size.

Comment: creating a Notepad file and then everything messed up. ..... but my taskbar got shrinked:     .....  The registry changes appear to have messed other things up. You may need to back up your computer and reinstall Windows

Comment: Yeah the last option

Comment: (1) Are your desktop icons and their labels of a normal size? (2) Try to show the taskbar labels in *Settings > Personalisation > Taskbar settings > Tàskbar > Combine taskbar buttons* to Never. (3) Can you use System Restore to rollback to before you did the change?

Comment: 1)desktop icons and labels were affected but changing size in personalization ,display corrected them but not the icons and font in taskbar. 2)this does nothing to size only shows what is going on in programs 3) yes system restore can solve this issue but that will remove installed applications

Comment: i just went to default font by using notepad file which that webpage had for reversing . thankyou everyone .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Right-click on the taskbar.
2. Choose Taskbar settings
3. Uncheck the "use small taskbar buttons" option.

Comment: no its not that i already checked that